# Protractor detect page refresh

Tags: javascript, protractor

How can I detect a page refresh using Protractor?  The page is displaying the results of a build occurring on the backend, and refreshes when the build finishes.

Currently, my code manually refreshes the page in a loop along these lines:

```
browser.wait(function () {
  browser.refresh().then(function () {
    return checkIfBuildFinished();
  });
});
```

Browser refreshes in a while loop - probably not the best practice here.

I've also tried checking for elements on the page, but Protractor breaks as soon as the refresh happens, as the object I'm inspecting is old.

Comment: I suggest you check for element on the page. Otherwise is a dead-end. How does it breaks? with StaleElementError ?

Comment: @LeoGallucci Yes, Stale element.

Comment: I think that's the real problem, [tried here to convince](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/543#issuecomment-42484545) that should be catch'ed Protractor-side with no luck.

Comment: I forked jasminewd to deal with it, and it has worked great for me: https://github.com/juliemr/webdriverjs-retry/issues/1#issuecomment-45144725

Comment: @LeoGallucci I don't think that's the core problem here - I need to detect a page refresh, not overcome a stale element.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 I think what Leo was trying to say is that the Stale element error is actually a sign that the page was refreshed. You may rely on it.